# Svn server and multiple disks

Tags: partitioning, mount, disk, svn

I have a small problem with svn configuration on my Ubuntu system. My main svn path is `/var/www/svn` and everything is working correctly with it, but I would like to add a second physic disk and use to extend `/var/www/svn` catalog. Here is the problem I stumbled upon. When I mount my `/dev/sda1` to `/var/www/svn/Data` catalog (Data is created to be a mount point for sda1) and use `svnadmin create` to init new repository, I got an error that said  "Could not find the requested SVN filesystem". I'm a little confused, maybe I should use some symlink to get it working with second disk or it is just impossible to make such a setup?

Best,
Kuba

Comment: What are the ownership and permissions on /var/www/svn/Data ? What filesystem exists on /dev/sda1 ?

Comment: /dev/sda1 has been formated to ext4 filesysytem. Catalog has this in details "drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data ". I set ownership for this folder after mount new disk to it.  Is this could cause the problem? The other repository that is placed on my system disk has the same ownership and works.

Comment: Quick update. Steps that let me make it working:
1. Make new catalog in /var/www/svn/ for mount with mkdir
2. Mount there new disk
3. Make new repo with svnadmin create in this folder
4. Run chmod and chown on this catalog.